# default values for mixins parameters

Tags: less, less-mixins

I am using a mixin for font like this:

```
#font {
  .trebuchet(@weight: normal, @size: 12px, @lineHeight: 20px, @style:normal) {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: @size;
    font-weight: @weight;
    line-height: @lineHeight;
    font-style: @style;
  }  
}
```

I want to call this changing only the last parameter, style, but leave the other values to their defaults. For example, instead of writing:

```
#font > .trebuchet(normal, 12px, 20px, italic);
```

I would write something like:

```
#font > .trebuchet(false, false, false, italic);
```

(which actually works, but I suspect for the wrong reasons -or anyway it doesn't seem proper syntax)
What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: See [Named Parameters](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-named-parameters), e.g. `.trebuchet(@style: italic);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pattern matching. You should clone your .trebuchet class like this:

```
.trebuchet when (@weight=false) and (not(ispixel(@size)) and (not(ispixel(@lineHeight)) {
    font-style: @style;
}
```